# Given an angle in degrees, how can I find the logic for line of travel using x and y? (Math dilemma)

Tags: math, html, canvas

I am making a simple game in HTML5 canvas, it involves driving a little car.

The up arrow moves the car, the left and right arrow steers it.

I have rotation sorted, but now it needs to move its x and y position when holding the up key, based on what angle it is at.

Example:

Angle is 0, the up arrow will only affect the y coordinate.

Angle is 45, the up arrow will affect both x and y coordinates at an equal pace.

What logic can I use if the angle is say, 32?

Comment: Wouldn't a 90 degree angle affect only the x coordinate?

Comment: Should the car have any momentum at all? If so, then both mass and force will need to be utilized.

Comment: Sorry, I meant 45. I am going to implement momentum once basic controls are working :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try something like this

```
   velY = Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * thrust;
   velX = Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * thrust;

    x += velX;
    y -= velY;
```

Quick example, angle is just incremented every loop.

http://jsfiddle.net/j5U5h/5/

Angle 0 is up like you have in your initial question.

Here is the jsfiddle modified so the angle of 0 moves you to the right.

http://jsfiddle.net/j5U5h/7/

```
 velX = Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * thrust;
 velY = Math.sin(angle * Math.PI / 180) * thrust;

 x += velX;
 y += velY;
```

To make 0 go to the right initially just change to this,

```
velX = -Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) * thrust;
```

Comment: `thrust` should go outside the parens -- apart from that you beat me to it :)

Comment: And note that in the OP, the angle 0 is along the y axis, while you adopted the usual mathematical convention having 0 degrees pointing in x direction.

Comment: good job, but just change the x and y functions, if I can I'll upvote you (daily limit)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time. Only left and right keys affect the angle.

Comment: @Saeed, what do you mean change the x/y is it because of the unusual angles he is using?

Comment: What Saeed meant, was that @Henryz specified that 0º points along the yy axis, while your solution points along the xx axis (like Sven said before).

Comment: The above does work great, it's exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @Loktar, because 0 degree has just movement in Y axis

Comment: Hi Loktar, may I ask you one more thing? The answer you gave gives my program the behavior I wanted but how can I make 0 degrees move along the y axis instead of x? I've tried to swap values around but with no luck. Thanks!

Comment: Henryz, so you want the angle of 0 to move you left, or right? Ill modify the js fiddle for you.

Comment: Ahhhh, excellent! Your JS Fiddle has put me on the right path. I remember sin/cos/tan from school but I should have paid attention haha. I have movement working, I guess now it's time to work out momentum. Do you have any experience with that too? I could post another question.

Comment: I have some experience, I would post another question though, lots of people have way more experience than myself so I know you'll get some great answers.

Answer (score 1):

Did you really mean that 90 moves both axes equally? It seems to me that it should be 45 moves both axes equally.

if 45 moves both axes equally:

```
xfactor = angle * (1/90)
yfactor = (90 - angle) * (1/90)

xpos = xpos + (xincrement * xfactor)
ypos = ypos + (yincrement * yfactor)
```

if 90 moves both axes equally:

```
xfactor = (2 * angle) * (1/180)
yfactor = (180 - (2 * angle)) * (1/180)

xpos = xpos + (xincrement * xfactor)
ypos = ypos + (yincrement * yfactor)
```

Comment: Hi, I did mean 45 degrees. I have tried to get this working, but with no luck. :(